# Build maven project in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, intellij-plugin, jogetworkflow

Hi i am trying to build a maven project in intellij, it build successfully but when i upload that plugin to the server (in joget). i get this error

```
ERROR 26 Sep 2018 10:22:35 org.joget.plugin.base.PluginManager  - Failed bundle start for com.sunway.saf.SafJdeInegration [791]: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle com.sunway.saf.SafJdeInegration [791].
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle com.sunway.saf.SafJdeInegration [791].
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2273)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2141)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:964)
    at org.joget.plugin.base.PluginManager.startBundle(PluginManager.java:292)
    at org.joget.plugin.base.PluginManager.upload(PluginManager.java:544)
    at org.joget.apps.app.controller.ConsoleWebController.consoleSettingPluginUploadSubmit(ConsoleWebController.java:3839)
    at org.joget.apps.app.controller.ConsoleWebController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e1402d89.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at org.joget.apps.app.controller.ConsoleWebController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$82516221.consoleSettingPluginUploadSubmit(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1112.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.joget.commons.spring.web.ParameterizedAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(ParameterizedAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.joget.apps.workflow.security.WorkflowHttpAuthProcessingFilter.doFilter(WorkflowHttpAuthProcessingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.joget.commons.spring.web.CustomDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(CustomDelegatingFilterProxy.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.joget.apps.app.web.ExpireFilter.doFilter(ExpireFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**here is my pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sunway.saf</groupId>
    <artifactId>SafJdeInegration</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>SafJdeInegration</name>
    <url>http://www.joget.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <!-- Change package and plugin class here -->
                        <Export-Package>com.sunway.saf</Export-Package>
                        <Private-Package>com.sunway.saf</Private-Package>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.sunway.saf.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>!*,org.joget.report.dao,org.joget.report.model,org.joget.report.service,org.joget.commons.util,org.joget.plugin.base,org.joget.plugin.property.model,org.joget.plugin.property.service,org.joget.directory.model,org.joget.directory.model.service,org.joget.directory.dao,org.joget.workflow.model,org.joget.workflow.model.dao,org.joget.workflow.model.service,org.joget.workflow.util,org.joget.apps.app.dao,org.joget.apps.app.lib,org.joget.apps.app.model,org.joget.apps.app.service,org.joget.apps.datalist.lib,org.joget.apps.datalist.model,org.joget.apps.datalist.service,org.joget.apps.form.lib,org.joget.apps.form.dao,org.joget.apps.form.model,org.joget.apps.form.service,org.joget.apps.list.service,org.joget.apps.userview.lib,org.joget.apps.userview.model,org.joget.apps.userview.service,org.joget.apps.workflow.lib,javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http,org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"</Import-Package>
                        <!-- End change package and plugin class here -->
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        <Embed-Directory>dependency</Embed-Directory>
                        <Embed-StripGroup>true</Embed-StripGroup>
                        <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joget</groupId>
            <artifactId>wflow-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Change plugin specific dependencies here -->

        <!-- End change plugin specific dependencies here -->
    </dependencies>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <url>http://dev.joget.org/archiva/repository/internal</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://dev.joget.org/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

while building the project, intellij downloads many dependencies itself, dont know where is the problem. i have tried creating new plugin and than try, even i edited and removed everything from one working plugin (working in netbeans) and made it to for my code. but as soon as i build it using intellij and uploaded, i started showing same error.

**This is my activator class**

```
package com.sunway.saf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    protected Collection<ServiceRegistration> registrationList;

    public void start(BundleContext context) {
        registrationList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Register plugin here
        registrationList.add(context.registerService(JdeDataIntegration.class.getName(), new JdeDataIntegration(), null));
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) {
        for (ServiceRegistration registration : registrationList) {
            registration.unregister();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after head hunting of 2 days, i finally resolved the issue. the problem was in my main class, the class which is used in activator class. I had a method in which I was using multi catch for a try block and multi catch is not supported when your source in below 1.7. and also I was casting a object to integer directly which is also not supported in source below than 1.7

**This was my main class**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.sunway.saf;

/**
 *
 * @author rizi
 */

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import org.joget.apps.form.model.Element;
import org.joget.apps.form.model.FormData;
import org.joget.commons.util.LogUtil;
import org.joget.plugin.base.PluginWebSupport;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class JdeDataIntegration extends Element implements PluginWebSupport {

    public final String urltoken="";
    public final String urldata="";
    public final String userName="";
    public final String password="";
    public String Token="";


    @Override
    public String renderTemplate(FormData formData, Map dataModel) {
        return "";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "SAF - JDE Integration";
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return "1.0.0";
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return "SAF - /jw/web/json/plugin/com.sunway.saf.JdeDataIntegration/service";
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return "SAF - JDE Integration";
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }

    public String getPropertyOptions() {
        return "";
    }
  public void webService(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {


      LogUtil.info("rizibhai..................", "plugin started.....");
      Value Vobj1 = new Value();
      Vobj1.setContent("00098");
      Vobj1.setSpecialValueId("LITERAL");


      List<Value> valueList1= new ArrayList<Value>();
      valueList1.add(Vobj1);

      Value Vobj2 = new Value();
      Vobj2.setContent("SM");
      Vobj2.setSpecialValueId("LITERAL");

      List<Value> valueList2= new ArrayList<Value>();
      valueList2.add(Vobj2);

      Value Vobj3 = new Value();
      Vobj3.setContent("01/01/17");
      Vobj3.setSpecialValueId("LITERAL");

      List<Value> valueList3= new ArrayList<Value>();
      valueList3.add(Vobj3);

      Condition Cobj1 = new Condition();
      Cobj1.setControlId("F4211.CO");
      Cobj1.setOperator("EQUAL");
      Cobj1.setValue(valueList1);

      Condition Cobj2 = new Condition();
      Cobj2.setControlId("F4211.DCTO");
      Cobj2.setOperator("EQUAL");
      Cobj2.setValue(valueList1);

      Condition Cobj3 = new Condition();
      Cobj3.setControlId("F4211.UPMJ");
      Cobj3.setOperator("GREATER_EQUAL");
      Cobj3.setValue(valueList1);

      List<Condition> conditionList1 = new ArrayList<Condition>();
      conditionList1.add(Cobj1);
      conditionList1.add(Cobj2);
      conditionList1.add(Cobj3);


      Query Qobj1= new Query();
      Qobj1.setAutoClear(true);
      Qobj1.setAutoFind(true);
      Qobj1.setCondition(conditionList1);
      Qobj1.setMatchType("MATCH_ALL");

      JSONStructure obj=new JSONStructure();
      obj.setAliasNaming(true);
      obj.setDataServiceType("BROWSE");
      obj.setDeviceName("MyDevice");
      obj.setLangPref("  ");
      obj.setMaxPageSize("2000");
      obj.setOutputType("VERSION1");
      obj.setPassword("!J0g3t6000");
      obj.setQuery(Qobj1);
      obj.setReturnControlIDs("F4211.DOCO|F4211.TRDJ|F4211.CRCD|F4211.AN8|F4211.DSC2|F4211.DSC1|F4211.LITM|F4211.LOTN|F4211.UORG|F4211.UPRC|F4211.AEXP");
      obj.setTargetName("F4211");
      obj.setTargetType("table");
      obj.setToken(Token);
      obj.setUsername("JOGET");

      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues().serializeNulls().create();
      LogUtil.info("rizibhai..................",gson.toJson(obj));

      HttpRequest(urltoken,obj.toString());

  }
    private HashMap HttpRequest(String url, String jsonParam) throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // send parameter
        if (jsonParam != null) {
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
                wr.writeBytes(jsonParam);
                wr.flush();
            }
        }

        HashMap result = new HashMap();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        result.put("responseCode", responseCode);

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
            }
        } else {
            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()))) {
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
            }
        }

        result.put("response", response.toString());
        LogUtil.info(getClassName(),response.toString());
        return result;
    }
    private HashMap getToken(String url, String jsonBody){

        HashMap result=null;

        try {
            result = HttpRequest(url , jsonBody);
            String response = (String) result.get("response");
            int responseCode = (int) result.get("responseCode");

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                Object o = p.parse(response);
                if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject resultObject = (JSONObject) o;
                    JSONObject userInfo = (JSONObject) resultObject.get("userInfo");
                    String token = (String) userInfo.get("token");
                    LogUtil.info(getClassName(), "Token is here alia bhatt....."+token );
                    result.put("token", token);
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException | ParseException | IOException ex) {
            LogUtil.error(getClassName(), ex, ex.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**And this was the problem**

```
catch (NullPointerException | ParseException | IOException ex) {
            LogUtil.error(getClassName(), ex, ex.toString());
        }
```